# What't the common way to support both PyQt4 and PyQt5 in one application?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I want to make an application that will work with both PyQt4 and PyQt5.

First of all I can create compatibility module `compat.py` that will fallback to PyQt4 if PyQt5 wasn't found:

```
try:
    __import__('PyQt5')
    use_pyqt5 = True
except ImportError:
    use_pyqt5 = False

if use_pyqt5:
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon as QIcon
else:
    from PyQt4.QtGui import QIcon as QIcon
```

After that I can import Qt-related classes from that module and check `compat.use_pyqt5` where PyQt4/5 has difference in logic.

Problem is that I want to make Qt version configurable and dependent on command-line options - and they're loaded in different module.

Comment: See: [Differences Between PyQt4 and PyQt5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html). Porting from PyQt4 to PyQt5 can be quite easy, but it depends a lot on the details of each application. My hunch is that maintaining a single code-base could become a bit of a nightmare in the long-term (i.e. once the project started to become larger and/or more complex).

Comment: @ekhumoro Maintaining is not a big problem in my case as gui part of project (namely [that one](https://github.com/anlar/prismriver)) is small and mostly finished. I've already added support for qt4 and qt5, but to switch between them I should manually edit source code (e.g. change `compat.use_pyqt5` variable) and I want to do it using command-line options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not really about supporting both PyQt4 and PyQt5. All it is really asking is: how do I access command-line options globally?

One solution is to add an `options` object to the module that processes the command-line options. This object could be a simple namespace that stores whatever options were read in and otherwise provides appropriate defaults. You would then just need to ensure that the `options` object was fully initialized *before* being imported by any other modules that might need it.

With that in place, you would the be able to do something like this:

```
from utils import options

use_pyqt5 = False

if options.try_pyqt5:

    try:
        import PyQt5
        use_pyqt5 = True
    except ImportError:
        pass
```